# Viewing pending lazy umount's on Linux

Tags: linux

The MNT_DETACH feature was added into Linux 2.4.11.

In a large environment where you have many system administrators, it's possible that the lazy umount command may be executed by more than 1 administrator.

How can you see the pending lazy umount commands which are executed from the "umount -l /mountpoint" command.  There is no process in memory displaying this information nor anything in the logfiles.  I've also been unable so far to find any information in /proc or /sys.

Comparing /etc/fstab to /etc/mtab is not a reliable method.

This information must be stored somewhere on the system, could SystemTap expose the lazy umount data for example via a data structure ?